# Power BI Desktop - Counting Items in a bucket over a date range

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to count commodity movements over a date range.

Details:
Rail car A contains Commodity Corn. It is loaded on 11/1/2018 and is unloaded 11/3/2018.

I have a custom date table(don't know if I need this) that shows an entry for each day, whether there is data or not.

In my dataset, I have a row of data that expresses the LoadNumber, Commodity, Load Date, and Unload Date.

I have this working in as much that the graph is showing each commodities start date.

I need to show on a graph that there was one load of Corn on the rails from 11/1/2018 to 11/3/2018. If there are multiple loads during that time frame, then the graph should reflect that by adding the value to the relevant dates commodity bar. We are currently using excel to populate the Data, but will eventually switch to query, if that makes any difference.(I want to rely on as little excel magic as possible)

[image: Chart Example]

Comment: You can do this with Pivot tables or the subtotal feature: https://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to see if that's available in pbi. Still getting used to it. Since this will be a live query we don't want to rely on excel if we don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a measure to count the loads for any given date:

```
Loads On Date =
VAR MinDate =
    MIN ( DateTable[Date] )
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( DateTable[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( LoadTable[LoadNumber] ),
        LoadTable[Load Date] <= MinDate,
        LoadTable[Unload Date] >= MaxDate
    )
```

Here's a worked example PBIX file: https://excel.solutions/loads-by-date/

Comment: thank  you, the analyst I am working with is out this week, but I will definitely give this a try once she is back and I have access to the data again.